# How to stop vlc from command line

Tags: windows, vlc

How does one stop vlc from command line, say at the 6:00 minute mark and quit vlc?,

Comment: How are you _starting_ VLC? What OS are you on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013503/capture-video-from-vlc-command-line-with-a-stop-time

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. I'm starting vlc from command line

Answer (score 4):

To end VLC after the video/song ends, you can add this at the end of your command line:

```
 vlc://quit
```

Example:

```
 vlc "C:\Users\Fenikkel\Music\Heartbeat.mp3" vlc://quit
```

Answer (score 2):

You can quit any process by searching for its name and killing it from the command line. Here is an example with vlc.

`killall -9 VLC`

Answer (score 2):

Windows has TASKKILL command which ends one or more tasks or processes
[TASKKILL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill)

You can kill process using image name.

```
TASKKILL /IM VLC.EXE
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes on Linux system VLC media player got hanged and we don't know what to do even we are doing quit but nothing help, to resolve this issue you can use based on name `pkill`

```
pkill vlc
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
pkill -9 vlc
```